# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'iie27cmjouht24y424g44s5qlm999vcj' in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following `views.py`:

```
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from student.models import CustomUser
from student.forms import UserForm
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from .models import UserSession

def user_logged_in_handler(sender,request,CustomUser,**kwargs):
    UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
        user=CustomUser,
        session_id= request.session.session_key
        )
user_logged_in.connect(user_logged_in_handler)

def delete_user_sessions(CustomUser):
    user_sessions=UserSession.objects.filter(user=CustomUser)
    for user_session in user_sessions:
        user_session.session.delete()
```

I have the following `models.py`:

```
class UserSession(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    session=models.ForeignKey(Session)
```

Also in `models.py` I have class `CustomUser(AbstractUser)`. What's wrong in my `views.py` as the error says when I try to access /admin/

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'iie27cmjouht24y424g44s5qlm999vcj'
```

The full `models.py` is as follows:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    addr1= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    addr2= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country= models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=country_choices)
    pincode= models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,null=True)
    securityq= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    securitya= models.CharField(max_length=20)

class userresp(models.Model):

    uid=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True,null=True)
    resp=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    datetime=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{} {}".format(self.uid,self.datetime)

    class Meta:
        db_table="userresp"

class UserSession(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    session=models.ForeignKey(Session)
```

What can I do here?

Comment: Can you post the full error message? Where is the error occurring?

Comment: the error is sorted...def user_logged_in_handler(sender,request,user,**kwargs):
    UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
        user=user
        session_id= request.session.session_key
        )
user_logged_in.connect(user_logged_in_handler)

Answer (score 0):

he error is sorted...

```
def user_logged_in_handler(sender,request,user, **kwargs):
    UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
        user= user,
        session_id= request.session.session_key
        )
user_logged_in.connect(user_logged_in_handler, sender=CustomUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from this line in your code `session_id= request.session.session_key`. Django expects the session id to be an `int` but the session key being generated is `string`. Check and make sure that you are asking for the correct data.